# Use $_POST['value'] inside functions.php

Tags: functions

Is it possible to use a value stored in POST on a page inside the functions.php file?

First on the . after the "20" I want to add the category__in value to the query_vars. And thats where I want to return the values stored in a POST which I submit trough a form on the page

```
// set number of projects displayed for pagination
function project_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'watches' )
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 20 .
        $query->query_vars['category__in'] = 53;

        // This should be something like this:
        // $query->query_vars['category__in'] = $_POST['category'];

        // So when I select one, or more categories in my checkbox based form it updates the pagination                 

    return $query;
}
if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'project_posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: It should be pretty easy to answer this question for yourself, just try it, but what exactly are you trying to do and how is it WordPress specific?

Comment: I am trying to get pagination to respond to my category selection form. Ill post the code in a edit, moment

Comment: So first of, I can't add another value to the `$query->query_vars`, and second, I don't know how to return the `$_POST['category']`

Comment: `query_vars` are `GET` parameters. What is the relationship to `POST`?